# Building a jquery ad with multiple behaviors

Tags: javascript, jquery, behavior, ads

I'm thinking this might be a long shot but am hoping for at least a reference link or even a little code to get me started.

I have a 960x300 ad that on page load should display for 3 seconds, then shrink to the top 30 pixels, basically becoming a 960x30 div.  After it completes that behavior, clicking on the ad should toggle the div between the 960x300 and 960x30 sizes.

I already struggled to build a similar setup but only where it toggles on hover, not on click, and the ad isn't initially displayed then shrinks on page load.  I'm a javascript novice at best so speak slowly and use small words. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to do the trick.

```
$('#mybigad').delay(3000).animate({height:30}, function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        if ($(this).height()==30) {
            $(this).animate({height:300});
        } else {
            $(this).animate({height:30});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect!  Worked like a charm.  All hail the javascript coders!! :)